# Is it possible to allow numbers, maybe booleans, for systemProperty values, in addition to strings

Tags: karate

We would like to use a number, possibly a boolean in the future, value for some karate.property settings, but this does not appear to be allowed, boolean currently sent as string.  We use this value, karate.dsRow, to determine which account entry we should use within our json test data file, based on the index passed in, within the Background of each feature file.

```
  Background: Authentication PreRequisites 
    * def dataSourceRow = karate.get('karate.dsRow', 1)
    * def dataSourceEnv = karate.get('karate.env', 'dev')
    * callonce read('../../../../service-config.js') { dsRow: '#(dataSourceRow)' , env: '#(dataSourceEnv)' }
```

[image: string value limitation for systemProperty]

Answer (score 1):

Behind the scenes, `karate.properties` are strings, delegating to the OS system properties etc. Karate has no control over this.

What I suggest is do the conversions when you unpack the variables (I assume from `karate.properties['some.name']`. Refer: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#type-conversion

```
* def fooString = karate.properties['some.bool'] || 'false'
* def foo = fooString === 'true'

* def barString = karate.properties['some.int'] || '8'
* def bar = parseInt(barString)
```